# Jest spyOn call count after mock implementation throwing an error

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

I have a program that makes three `post` requests in this order

1. http://myservice/login
2. http://myservice/upload
3. http://myservice/logout

The code looks something like this

```
async main() {
    try {
        await this.login()
        await this.upload()
    } catch (e) {
        throw e
    } finally {
        await this.logout()
    }
  }
```

where each method throws its own error on failure.

I'm using Jest to spy on the underlying request library (superagent). For one particular test I want to test that the logout `post` request is being made if the upload function throws an error.

I'm mocking the `post` request by throwing an exception.

```
const superagentStub = {
    post: () => superagentStub
}

const postSpy = jest.spyOn(superagent, 'post')
  .mockImplementationOnce(() => superagentStub)
  .mockImplementationOnce(() => { throw new Error() })
  .mockImplementationOnce(() => superagentStub)

const instance = new ExampleProgram();

expect(async () => await instance.main()).rejects.toThrow(); // This is fine
expect(postSpy).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(3, 'http://myservice/logout')
```

If I don't mock the third implementation, the test will fail as `logout()` will throw its own `error` since the third `post` request will fail as a live call.

The spy in this case reports that only 1 call is made to the `post` method of the underlying library.

1. http://myservice/login

I find this strange because I am expecting 3 calls to the spy

1. http://myservice/login
2. http://myservice/upload  -> but it throws an error
3. http://myservice/logout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please keep in mind how to use `expect(...).rejects.toThrow()`. It's a bit tricky, though: https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#rejects

*BTW: It's always nice to have ESLint active when coding with JavaScript. The following rule might then warn you about your error: https://github.com/jest-community/eslint-plugin-jest/blob/main/docs/rules/valid-expect.md ("Async assertions must be awaited or returned.")*

### Solution

You are missing an `await` in the beginning of the second-last line of your test-code. Replacing that line with the following should hopefully solve your problem:

```js
await expect(() => instance.main()).rejects.toThrow();
```

which is the same as

```js
await expect(async () => await instance.main()).rejects.toThrow();
```

You state `// This is fine` in your variant, but actually it isn't. You have a "false positive", there. Jest will most likely also accept the second-last line of your test even if you negate it, i.e. if you replace `.rejects.toThrow()` with `.rejects.not.toThrow()`.

*If you have more than one test in the same test-suite, Jest might instead state that some later test fails - even if it's actually the first test which causes problems.*

### Details

Without the new `await` in the beginning of the given line, the following happens:

1. `expect(...).rejects.toThrow()` initiates `instance.main()` - but doesn't wait for the created Promise to resolve or reject.
2. The beginning of `instance.main()` is run synchronously up to the first `await`, i.e. `this.login()` is called.
3. Mostly because your mockup to `superagent.post()` is synchronous, `this.login()` will return immediately. *BTW: It might be a good idea to always replace async functions with an async mockup, e.g. using `.mockResolvedValueOnce()`.*
4. The Promise is still pending; JavaScript now runs the last line of your test-code and Jest states that your mockup was only used once (up to now).
5. The test is aborted because of that error.
6. The call to `instance.main()` will most likely continue afterwards, leading to the expected error inside `instance.main()`, a rejected Promise and three usages of your mockup - but all this after the test already failed.

Comment: Yes that was is exactly! And our linter has `valid-expect` enabled but without `alwaysAwait`, so thank you for pointing out that gotcha too as well as the others